# Can you override the default sendmail path in Sendmail transport config in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, emails

Many shared hosting accounts require custom flags that are passed to sendmail in order for them to work properly.

Since Craft 3 uses [Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer) for its mailing library and Swiftmailer's default Sendmail command is `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs` (https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/SendmailTransport.php#L30), is there a way to override that from Craft's `config/app.php` to set a custom sendmail command?

Comment: Are you aware that `-bs` makes sendmail talk SMTP over stdin&stdout?

Comment: I had no idea @AnFi!

Answer (score 3):

There are some examples of how to override the mailer component and transport settings in the official Craft docs here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#mailer-component

For this particular sendmail example, you'd need to do something like this from `config/app.php`:

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => function() {
        // Get the stored email settings
        $settings = Craft::$app->systemSettings->getEmailSettings();

        // Override the transport adapter class
        $settings->transportType = craft\mail\transportadapters\Sendmail::class;

        // Create a Mailer component config with these settings
        $config = craft\helpers\App::mailerConfig($settings);
        $config['transport']['command'] = '/usr/bin/sendmail -customflags';

        // Instantiate and return it
        return Craft::createObject($config);
    },
]
```